# Why does it display the value "null" if the conditions of the method are met?

Tags: java, loops

I'm trying to compile my first major program. Unfortunately in getBestFare() I get "null" coming out all the time. And it shouldn't! I'm asking you guys for help what's wrong.

I rebuilt the entire getBestFare() method but unfortunately it keeps coming up with "null". The earlier code was a bit more messy. Now it's better, but it still doesn't work.

```
public class TransitCalculator {
    public int numberOfDays;
    public int transCount;

    public TransitCalculator(int numberOfDays, int transCount) {
        if(numberOfDays <= 30 && numberOfDays > 0 && transCount > 0){
        this.numberOfDays = numberOfDays;
        this.transCount = transCount;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid data.");
        }
    }

    String[] length = {"Pay-per-ride", "7-day", "30-day"};
    double[] cost = {2.75, 33.00, 127.00};

    public double unlimited7Price(){
        int weekCount = numberOfDays/7;
        if (numberOfDays%7>0){
            weekCount+=1;
        }
        double weeksCost = weekCount * cost[1];
        return weeksCost;
    }

    public double[] getRidePrices(){
        double price1 = cost[0];
        double price2 = ((cost[1]*unlimited7Price()) / (unlimited7Price() * 7));
        double price3 = cost[2] / numberOfDays;

        double[] getRide = {price1, price2, price3};
        return getRide;
    }

    public String getBestFare(){
        int num = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < getRidePrices().length; i++) {
            if(getRidePrices()[i] < getRidePrices()[num]){
                    return "You should get the " + length[num] + " Unlimited option at " + getRidePrices()[num]/transCount + " per ride.";
                }
        }
        return null;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args){
        TransitCalculator one = new TransitCalculator(30, 30);

        System.out.println(one.unlimited7Price());
        System.out.println(one.getRidePrices()[2]);
        System.out.println(one.getBestFare());

    }
}
```

Comment: The code in `getBestFare()` tries to find the ride price that is better than the first ride price (`getRidePrices()[num]` with `num` always being equal to 0 which result in `getRidePrices()[num]` being equal to 2.75). Since there is no better ride price (they are 2.75, 4.714... and 4.2333...) the condition of the `if` statement is never fulfilled and you end up at the last return statement (`return null;`)

Comment: Thank you Thomas for your reply. So I understand that I need to add more conditional "if" statements to getBestFare() to better sort this code.